# Why am I still a product owner when I switched sandbox user using cordova-plugin-purchase for subscription payments?

Tags: cordova

I'm using `cordova-plugin-purchase` and I'm still a subscriber for the product after signing in with a different apple store account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because `cordova-plugin-purchase` caches a bunch of things in `localStorage` such as owned status and receipts that were getting validated. Fixed with `localStorage.clear();` and a reload.